# How to compile a cpp file in command line on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, powershell, cmd

https://github.com/GiacomoLaw/Keylogger/blob/master/windows/klog_main.cpp

I can following the following video (Visual Studio Community) to compile the above cpp file. (Source files -> Add -> New Item -> C++ file (.cpp))

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWJWUR-UnzQ

But I want to also be able to compile the .cpp file in the command line (in cmd.exe or powershell). How to figure out what the equivalent command line is?

EDIT:

I found the following `cl.exe` file. Which one should I use for the compilation and linking?

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20210112173110
Username: MSEDGEWIN10\IEUser
RunAs User: MSEDGEWIN10\IEUser
Configuration Name: 
Machine: MSEDGEWIN10 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 4300
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.1490
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.1490
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.1490
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\PowerShell_transcript.MSEDGEWIN10.9UiUmlLU.20210112173110.txt
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/30/2008   1:05 PM         129520 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin\amd64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/30/2008   2:58 PM         153584 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/30/2008   3:11 PM         128496 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/12/2021   8:54 AM         391088 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x86


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/12/2021   8:54 AM         392624 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx86\x64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/12/2021   8:54 AM         326064 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx86\x86


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/12/2021   8:54 AM         327088 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-ar---         6/9/2016  11:46 PM         190600 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-ar---         6/9/2016  11:53 PM         229000 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_arm


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-ar---         6/9/2016  11:53 PM         225568 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-ar---         6/9/2016  11:53 PM         229664 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-ar---         6/9/2016  11:46 PM         190752 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_arm


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-ar---         6/9/2016  11:46 PM         187168 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.1637.1.6\amd64_microsoft-wi
    ndows-wid-xtp_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1637_none_1ffeac885bc12e07\f


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        12/3/2020   1:13 PM            143 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.1637.1.6\amd64_microsoft-wi
    ndows-wid-xtp_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1637_none_1ffeac885bc12e07\r


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        12/3/2020   1:13 PM            143 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.379.1.11\amd64_microsoft-wi
    ndows-wid-xtp_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.348_none_475b451a0f823259\f


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/8/2019  12:24 AM            143 cl.exe


    Directory: C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.379.1.11\amd64_microsoft-wi
    ndows-wid-xtp_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.348_none_475b451a0f823259\r


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/8/2019  12:24 AM            143 cl.exe
```

Comment: Compile the "file", or a project or a solution? See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160

Comment: It refers to the .cpp file. The post has been updated.

Comment: See the linked article. There's a lot more to building than compiling. This entry point may be more useful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160

Comment: Search the internet for "Visual Studio Dev environment".  Much easier when you activate the develop environment.

Comment: Are you seriously, as a not new member here, expecting me to go to a web page for something, then watch a video on an advertising tracking site, before providing you with links to sites, books, tools, software libraries etc.

Comment: @3Dave I don't find `cl`. The Visual Studio Community 2019 is installed following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsAoIqnNia4. Is `cl` supposed to be missing in when VS is installed in this way? Thanks.

Comment: If you have visual studio installed, then you have cl. Open the visual studio command prompt, since it sets up additional paths for you.

Comment: If you want to find the path to `cl.exe`, first do what @ChrisMM suggests. When in VS2019, select `Tools\Command Line\Developer PowerShell`. Then give the command `Get-Command cl` and it'll show the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2017, I use the command line:
`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com Your_Solution.sln /Rebuild Release"`

Search the internet for the "Visual Studio devenv" and investigate the command line switches.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add cl.exe, vcvarsall.bat and other paths to the path environment variable:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt;
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx86\x86;
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE;
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build;

2. Add the path to the INCLUDE environment variable. If you do not have, create a new environment variable named INCLUDE.

I suggest you use the VS to view in `Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories`:
[image]

3. Add the path to the LIB environment variable. If you do not have, create the environment variable named LIB.

I suggest you use the VS to view in `Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories`:
[image]

4. Then, you could compile the .cpp with cmd `cl  -EHsc  XXX.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Open Developer Command Prompt (`Tools -> Command Line -> Developer Command Prompt`) from Visual Studio and run

`cl /EHsc <filename>.cpp`